# Add new chart.js when clicking a button, but get 'Cannot read property 'getContext' of null'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js

I like to add a new chart when clicking "add chart" button. The chart does not contain any data at the moment, but will be added later. Anyway, when I  click on "add chart" I get "`Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`". I think the problem is that my javascript is running before HTML has finished loading. But do not know how to fix it..  I have tried to use $jQuery .ready function, and add the script after the canvas tag..

My code:

app.js

```
'use strict';
require('angular');
require('angular-route');
require('angular-animate');
var chartsCtrl = require('./controllers/chartsCtrl');

var app = angular.module('DashBoard', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])

//Load controller
app.controller('chartsCtrl', ['$scope', chartsCtrl]);
```

chartsCtrl.js:

```
module.exports = function($scope) { 
var Chart = require('chart.js');

    $scope.charts = [];
    var chartId = 0;
    $scope.addChart = function() {
       chartId ++;
       $scope.charts.push({msg: 'Chart added!!', id: chartId});
       new Chart(document.getElementById(chartId).getContext('2d')).Line();
};

    $scope.closeChart = function(index) {
       $scope.charts.splice(index, 1);
    }; 
};
```

charts.html:

```
<div ng-controller='chartsCtrl'>  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{chart.msg}} {{chart.id}} <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="closeChart($index)"></i>
                    <canvas id={{chart.id}} width="400" height="200"> </canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: having a numeric id value is wrong (you could use something like `chart-{{chartId}}`). Maybe it will start to work if you change it

Comment: In addchart you increment a counter and then try to get the dom element with that id.  Does that dom element exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get the element before the view has finished rendering, inject `$timeout` to your controller and wrap the DOM manipulation part to make sure that the elements are already in the document, this should work:

```
module.exports = function($scope, $timeout) { 
    var Chart = require('chart.js');

    $scope.charts = [];
    var chartId = 0;

    function initChart( chartIt ) {
        $timeout(function() {
           new Chart(document.getElementById(chartId.toString()).getContext('2d')).Line();
        });
    }

    $scope.addChart = function() {
       chartId ++;
       $scope.charts.push({msg: 'Chart added!!', id: chartId});
       initChart( chartId );
    };

    $scope.closeChart = function(index) {
        $scope.charts.splice(index, 1);
    }; 
};
```